# How to make live chat like facebook in my web application?

Tags: web, chat, livechat

I want to build web applications with simple chat like facebook have, but If I wanna make a chat self service what will I have to accomplish that?

I just newbie and don't know the architecture of chat applications. The purpose is just I can to record the history of chat to my database..

If the resource is high, Can you suggest the free service online chat that I can integrate in my applications??

Any help regards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can using AJAX or Socket...
but i recommend you using Socket, because Socket is lighter than AJAX in your browser...
this socket example http://socket.io/demos/chat/

Answer (score 1):

[Phponlinechat](http://phponlinechat.com/) is a free chat support service. It is offering a online live chat as a service and as a software.You can download free [live chat](http://phponlinechat.com/) tool from here.

Answer (score -2):

If you want chat recording and a system that is very easy to integrate, you can look at [www.focalscope.com](http://www.focalscope.com). It is a help desk system, but it has a chat module and best of all, it’s free for startups (no feature limitations). I’ve been using it for my online business and the web chat was configured by me in 5 mins.